# CCM-AES from Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, cryptography, kernel, aes

I need to be compatible with Solaris crypto mech SUN_CKM_AES_CCM. In Linux, I believe I should setup an AEAD request to get "ccm(aes)" mech. Documentation for Linux Crypto does seem rather poor, the best example appears to be tcrypt.c test, and kernel sources.

From Solaris, I did a test encryption of a 512 byte block, with 16 byte hmac, and 12 byte iv. This needs to stay the same, and hopefully the results be identical.

However, what I *think* should would work, does not;

```
   struct crypto_aead *tfm = NULL;
   struct aead_request *req;
   unsigned char key[16] = {
    0x5c, 0x95, 0x64, 0x42, 0x00, 0x82, 0x1c, 0x9e,
    0xd4, 0xac, 0x01, 0x83, 0xc4, 0x9c, 0x14, 0x97
   };
  unsigned int ivsize;
  int ret;
  struct scatterlist plaintext[1];
  struct scatterlist ciphertext[1];
  struct scatterlist hmactext[1];
  unsigned char *plaindata = NULL;
  unsigned char *cipherdata = NULL;
  unsigned char *hmacdata = NULL;
  unsigned char *ivp = NULL;
  int i;
  unsigned char d;
  struct tcrypt_result result;

  tfm = crypto_alloc_aead("ccm(aes)", 0, 0);
  init_completion(&result.completion);
  req = aead_request_alloc(tfm, GFP_KERNEL);
  aead_request_set_callback(req, CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_BACKLOG,
                          cipher_work_done, &result);

  crypto_aead_clear_flags(tfm, ~0);

  ret = crypto_aead_setkey(tfm, key, sizeof(key));

  ret = crypto_aead_setauthsize(tfm, 16); // authsize is hmac?

  ivsize = crypto_aead_ivsize(tfm);
  if (ivsize != 12) {
    printk("ivsize is not 12 %d - this needs to be fixed\n", ivsize);
  }

  plaindata  = kmalloc(512, GFP_KERNEL);
  cipherdata = kmalloc(512, GFP_KERNEL);
  hmacdata   = kmalloc(16, GFP_KERNEL);
  ivp        = kmalloc(ivsize, GFP_KERNEL);

  if (!plaindata || !cipherdata || !hmacdata || !ivp) goto out;

  // put 00 01 02 03 ... in the input buffer...
  for (i = 0, d = 0; i < 512; i++, d++)
    plaindata[i] = d;

  memset(cipherdata, 0, 512);
  memset(hmacdata, 0, 16);
  memset(ivp, 0, ivsize);

  // Put a8 a9 aa .... in iv
  for (i = 0,d=0xa8; i < 12; i++, d++)
    ivp[i] = d;

  sg_init_one(&plaintext[0],  plaindata,  512);
  sg_init_one(&ciphertext[0], cipherdata, 512);
  sg_init_one(&hmactext[0],   hmacdata,   16);

  aead_request_set_crypt(req, plaintext, ciphertext, 512, ivp);

  aead_request_set_assoc(req, hmactext, 16);

  ret = crypto_aead_encrypt(req);

  printk("cipher call returns %d \n", ret);
```

And what we get back is that ivsize is 16 (and I see no way to set it to 12), and that encrypt fails with "-22" or EINVAL.  There are lots of errors checking in the code, removed here, that confirm all prior call return success.

As far as I can tell, I follow the tcrypt.c sources pretty close. However, I wonder if the forced `ivsize = 16` will mean I can not use the supplied algorithm anyway. That aside, it would be nice to see the encrypt call succeed and what is put in the cipherdata output.

The code is put into a kernel module, and run at _init() time. Initially I used blkcipher "aes", which works, but is not the ccm-aes variant. This made me change to use aead, which I can not get to work.

Comment: So, does it work with 16-byte IV? Probably they hardcoded such IV size. Also, there are two AEAD cipher modes - AEAD-CCM and AEAD-GCM.

Comment: CCM does not include HMAC, and you are saying that Solaris is using a HMAC. Which one is it?

Comment: The code sees that iv is 16, but keeps going. Then fails with -22 (EINVAL) and I'm not sure why the code does not work as it is the same as tcrypt.c (well, that I can see)

The Solaris code certainly gets a 16byte HMAC back, sha256 from what I can tell, so I need to do the same.

Perhaps I should then look at doing my own CCM-AES, by calling regular blkcipher aes + magic. Is that feasible?

Comment: Ok, EINVAL is due to

`static inline int crypto_ccm_check_iv(const u8 *iv)`

Which makes sure my first byte of iv, is between 1 and 7. Is that a real requirement? Now it "fails" with returncode "0", and the output buffer is modified. It is not correct, but a step forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this is what I have learnt.

1)
Let's call the Application's iv `nonce`. And let's call the internal crypto's iv `iv`. It turns out that the Solaris code is using `nonce-len=12`, but the CCM-AES algorithm still uses `iv-len=16`.

From Solaris kernel sources, `iv` is made up with:

```
iv[0] = 1..7, based on ivlen 16 - noncelen 12 = 2.
iv[1] = the nonce data (12 bytes).
iv[14] = 0
iv[15] = 1
```

So, on Linux I want "ccm(aes)" with ivlen 16, and prepare the `iv` from `nonce` properly.

2)
When calling `crypto_aead_encrypt()` the prior call of `aead_request_set_assoc()` is ignored, and HMAC is put at the end of the cipher buffer. In my case, at ciphertext[512], for 16 bytes. So the input needed to be +16 in length.

Using scatterlist, the HMAC "at the end" can be somewhere different if set up correctly.

3)
When calling `crypto_aead_decrypt()` the cryptolen should be +16 (cipherinputlen + maclen). The MAC is read from end of input buffer, ie, ciphertext[512] for 16 bytes. Which can also be a separate buffer using scatterlist.

4)
`crypto_aead_setauthsize()` checks that the len given is correct, then does nothing with it. Don't think this actually sets the size!

5) `aead_request_set_assoc()` has to be set, even if it is just to a buffer of zeros.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. The IV issues of CCM and awkward handling of AEAD data is enough for me to recommend GCM mode over CCM. There is nothing wrong cryptographically with CCM (as far as I know), but the protocol is not well thought out.

Comment: This is the only documentation on the entire internet which explains the arguments to the aead set of functions.

Comment: If it helps others, here is the completed sources; https://github.com/zfsrogue/spl-crypto/blob/master/module/spl/spl-crypto.c#L185

You can ignore the Solaris mapping UIO to Linux scatterlist etc. Also the COPY_DST is not used, I did my own version of "gcm" and "ccm" modules that fixes the panic in Linux kernel. The default ones can still panic.